# Is $Set$ a subcategory of $Grp$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am almost sure that the answer is not. However, we also know that in every non empty set there exists an opeation wich gives group structure. 
So, can we see each non empty set as a group?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

A category $C$ is defined by a class of object $Ob(C)$ and for every objects $A,B$ a set of morphisms $Hom_C(A,B)$. There does not exist an embedding functor $i:Set\rightarrow Grp$,
suppose that such a functor exists, take $S$ a finite set of cardinal $n>1$, you have an injective map $Hom_{Set}(S,S)\rightarrow Hom_{Grp}(i(S),i(S))$, this implies that every morphism of the set $i(S)$ is a morphism of its group structure, this is impossible, since there are morphisms $f$  of the set $i(S)$ such that $f(e)\neq e$ where $e$ is the neutral element of $i(S)$.

Comment: The "obvious" $i$ doesn't work, but what's wrong with taking e.g. $i(S)$ to be the free group generated by $S$?

Answer (score 1):

No - at least, not in the obvious way. For example, a two-element set $\{a, b\}$ has two automorphisms in the category **Set**, namely the identity automorphism and the automorphism that swaps $a$ and $b$. But, if we put a group structure on it, it only has one automorphism in the category **Grp**.

On the other hand, **Grp** can be seen as a subcategory of **Set** - more precisely, there is an obvious functor from **Grp** to **Set** which is injective on both objects and morphisms, sending each group to its underlying set. (It's called the *forgetful* functor.)

Comment: but there are sets were we can define several operations wich give different group structure

Comment: Of course, but any inclusion $I: \mathbf{Set} \to\mathbf{Grp}$ assigns to *each* set $X$ a *single* group $I(X)$.